# Android - Button on bottom of the screen and Keyboard starting on top of it

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible to have a button on the bottom of the screen and when i use the keyboard keep the button visible on the bottom and the keyboard on top of the button?

I dont need the button being pushed up with the keyboard or the keyboard going over the button.

I need the button usable and visible on the bottom of the screen and the keyboard on top of it.

- Edittext -
- Keyboard -
- Button -

Thanks!

Comment: afaik no option for that, you can't enforce other app to be shown in the middle of the screen

Comment: The only alternative that I see is implementing a dedicated keyboard view.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes, i think that the only way is with a custom keyboard view.

Comment: I really would not suggest doing that at all.  You can write your own keyboard, but its a LOT more complicated then you think to write a good one, you'd lose 90% of the features of a good keyboard, and no Android user ever would look under the keyboard for a button, we expect the keyboard to be at the bottom.  You're better off changing you design.

Comment: Yes, i totally agree with you. I am just investigating this options to deliver an answer to my team. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

In `Manifest.xml`. Add this line `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in activity tag

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    ...
```

Comment: It doesnt work. It will push the button upwards. Thanks for the response anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `Manifest.xml`

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ui.messages.ChatActivity"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```